# mod_rewrite old URL with query to new URL path

Tags: mod-rewrite

I've changed my website and for backwards compatibility I need to rewrite a set of old URLs with query parameters into specific new URL paths without parameters.

The old URLs are of the form:

```
www.mysite.com/portfolio.php?pid=x
```

with 'x' being some number. There could be more parameters after that first one, but I only need to match on the first one.

I want to map each of these to a URL of the form:

```
www.mysite.com/custom/item/some-item-name
```

I am not getting anywhere with this. I have tried, for example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} pid=13(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/portfolio\.php$ /custom/item/some\-item\-name [NC,L]
```

...but it never matches. I've gone through lots of examples, all with slightly different syntax. Help from someone who knows this stuff would be much appreciated!

Comment: You need to remove the leading `/`. So use `RewriteRule ^portfolio\.php$ /custom/item/some-item-name [NC,L]`. (PS. Note that the rewritecond will also match `pid=136`)